# Sequences and Greatest Integer Function

Tags: sequences-and-series, weak-convergence, ceiling-and-floor-functions, sequence-of-function

$u_1 = 1$

$u_{n+1} = u_n + 1/u_n$ for $n > 1$.

Find $\lfloor 50u_{100}\rfloor$, where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ represents the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

Kindly give any clues/ideas on how to approach this problem. I know the answer via a simple program I wrote. (Answer = $710$) How do I solve this analytically?

So far I've been able to see a pattern on $y = 1/x$ graph: start on $(1, 1)$ go down diagonally along $x+y=0$, hit x-axis and go straight up, hit the curve and keep repeating these right triangles. Not sure if this helps but I'm not able to proceed any further.
[image]

Comment: Correction: my last comment had typos, so I deleted it.  I meant to write that the sequence $\{\lfloor u_n\rfloor\}$ is surprisingly close to the sequence $\{\lfloor \sqrt {2n}\rfloor\}$.  Indeed, the sequences mostly coincide, though they differ (by $1$) at $n=24, 40, \cdots$.

Comment: I think the answer can be concluded from the asymptotics of that sequence  studied here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2620206/42969 and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29777/42969.